# serialize() value wrong on second call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I have a page that I'm calling that has a form submission within an ajax call.  When the function is called a second time, it has the original data in the ajax call data.

I've simplified this with just the serialization portion here:

test_form.php

```
    function form($a, $b) {
    ?>
    <form name="myform" id="myform">
        <input type="text" id="a" name="a" value="<?php echo $a; ?>" />
        <input type="text" id="b" name="b" value="<?php echo $b; ?>" />
    </form>
    <script>
        console.log($("#myform").serialize());
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

This is then called from a separate file:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/P3Live/_includes/css/gametypes.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/P3Live/_includes/css/tables.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="/P3Live/_includes/js/general_functions.js"></script> 
</head>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
include_once("test_form.php");

form("firstA", "firstB");
echo "step # 1 should be started <br />";


form("secondA", "secondB");
echo "step # 2 should be started <br />";
?>
```

When the second file is fired, the results are:

HTML Page:
firstA (input box 1) firstB (input box 2)
step # 1 should be started

secondA (input box 1) secondB (input box 2)
step # 2 should be started

Console:
a=firstA&b=firstB
a-firstA&b=firstB

You'll notice that the input fields are correct, but the serialized data at the bottom is not.  It displays the same serialized data from the first call for both results.  I tried posting a screenshot, but do not have the reputation points to do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating two forms with the same ID, and as ID's are unique you're getting the data from the first form, as that's what jQuery selects when there are duplicate ID's, the first element with that ID.

Try creating forms with unique ID's

```
function form($a, $b, $id) {
    ?>
    <form name="myform" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        <input type="text" id="a" name="a" value="<?php echo $a; ?>" />
        <input type="text" id="b" name="b" value="<?php echo $b; ?>" />
    </form>
    <script>
        console.log($("#<?php echo $id; ?>").serialize());
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

and then do

```
form("firstA", "firstB", "myForm1");
form("secondA", "secondB", "myForm2");
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

it's because the ID for both forms is the same. You have to assign a new ID for the second form. It should be something like this:

```
<?php
function form($a, $b) {
    static $i = 0;
    ?>
    <form name="myform<?php echo $i; ?>" id="myform<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <input type="text" id="a" name="a" value="<?php echo $a; ?>" />
        <input type="text" id="b" name="b" value="<?php echo $b; ?>" />
    </form>
    <script>
        console.log($("#myform<?php echo $i; ?>").serialize());
    </script>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
```